# python for loop and dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.6, tryton

in python and tryton
I'm confused why I can't get the desired value I wanted; I don't know what's wrong.

Lets say `self.pendingapr` has a field `itemdescription` and have 3 indexes, overall it has `small`, `medium`, `large` in `itemdescriptions`. I really don't know if the problem's is in the for loop:

```
global M2Mdic
global M2Mldic2
M2Mdic = {}
M2Mldic2 = {}
res = {}

for x in self.pendingapr:
    M2Mdic['itemdescription'] = str(x.itemdescription)
    M2Mldic2[x.id] = M2Mdic
```

when i print M2Mldic2 it gives me

```
>>> {1:'large',2:'large',3:'large'}
```

when I need / and is expecting is

```
>>> {1:'small',2:'medium',3:'large'}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for all your answer, this lighten up my mind. actually all of your answers deserves to be check. but i cant.. so i rank up your replies. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that map variables are references in Python. So in each iteration if the loop you are modifying all M2Mldic2 maps because they are all the same.

I think your code should be:

```
#global M2Mdic
global M2Mldic2
M2Mdic = {}
M2Mldic2 = {}
res = {}

for x in self.pendingapr:
   M2Mdic = {}
   M2Mdic['itemdescription'] = str(x.itemdescription)
   M2Mldic2[x.id] = M2Mdic
```

Answer (score 2):

You are putting the same object into every value in the `M2Mldic2` dictionary.  Keep in mind that objects are generally passed by reference, you need to copy them explicitly when you want copies.

```
for x in self.pendingapr:
    M2Mdic = {
        'itemdescription': str(x.itemdescription)
    }
    M2Mldic2[x.id] = M2Mdic
```

This creates a separate dictionary for each value in `M2Mldic2`.

Comment: There is no need for M2Mdic at all!!

Answer (score 1):

And why you need intermediate dictionary at all? This is completely redundant

```
M2mDict={}
for x in self.pendingapr:
    M2Mldic2[x.id] = str(x.itemdescription)
```

or more Pythonic way(from v.2.7)

```
M2mDict= = {x.id : str(x.itemdescription) for  x in self.pendingapr}
```